# ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey in Admin::UsersController#destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

In ActiveAdmin, when I want to delete a user I have the following error :

```
ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey in Admin::UsersController#destroy 
PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR: update or delete on table "users" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_b080fb4855" on table "notifications" DETAIL: Key (id)=(15) is still referenced from table "notifications". : DELETE FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1
```

I already have `has_many :notifications,  dependent: :destroy` in my User model so I don't understand the error.

Notification model:

```
class Notification < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_validation :check_modeles

  validates :message, presence: true
  validates :modele, presence: true
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :contact_id, presence: true
  validates_associated :user

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :contact, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "contact_id"
```

User model :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_validation :check_genres
  before_validation :set_image
  before_validation :init_attrs
  before_create :set_name
  before_create :create_mangopay
  after_create :set_centres_interets
  after_create :set_preferences_musicales
  after_create :check_on_create
  after_update :check_on_update
  before_update :create_mangopay_bank_account
  before_destroy :remove_contact_notifications




  acts_as_mappable :default_units => :kms,
                   :lat_column_name => :last_lat,
                   :lng_column_name => :last_lng


  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
    :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable

  has_one :fil, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :preferences_voyage,  dependent: :destroy
  has_one :verification,  dependent: :destroy
  has_many :badges,  dependent: :destroy
  has_many :favoris ,  dependent: :destroy
  has_many :centres_interets,  dependent: :destroy
  has_many :preferences_musicales,  dependent: :destroy
  has_many :recommandations,  dependent: :destroy
  has_many :reputations,  dependent: :destroy
  has_many :reservations,  dependent: :destroy
  has_many :routes,  dependent: :destroy
  has_many :trajets_reguliers,  dependent: :destroy
  has_many :vehicules,  dependent: :destroy
  has_many :contact_notifications, foreign_key: 'contact_id', class_name: 'Notification', dependent: :destroy
  has_many :notifications,  dependent: :destroy
  has_many :recherches, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :blocages, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :messageries, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy

  validates :date_naissance, presence: true
  validates :first_name, presence: true
  validates :last_name, presence: true
```

Maybe the `has_many :notifications,  dependent: :destroy` only affect the user and not the contact? If so, how do i fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, maybe your best bet is to just remove the foreign key constraints.

Create a migration with the following lines

```
remove_foreign_key :notifications, :users
remove_foreign_key :notifications, column: :contact_id
```

Rails doesn't require the foreign key constraints, and they're clearly not helping here.

You can also remove it by name...

```
remove_foreign_key :notifications, name: :fk_rails_b080fb4855
```

Comment: I will see with the main dev to remove the keys because I don't want to broke the app haha

Answer (score 0):

In your PostgreSQL database table `notifications` you have two different foreign keys that relate to `users` the `user_id` and the `contact_id` and the `dependent: destroy` only relates to the `user_id`.

Add another `has_many` to your User model to cover the second association

```
has_many :contact_notifications, foreign_key: 'contact_id', class_name: 'Notification', dependent: :destroy
```

Also, ensure that you're using the `destroy` method when you're deleting a user

```
@user.delete # will NOT run callbacks
@user.destroy # will run callbacks including destroying dependent records
```

To be sure that the issue is related to `contact_id` you can try removing those records with a manual process

```
class User

  before_destroy :remove_contact_notifications

  def remove_contact_notifications
    Notification.where(contact_id: id).destroy_all
    Notification.where(user_id: id).destroy_all
  end

end
```

Comment: I've added another point to my answer, let me know if that helps!

Comment: Apparently, the method used in ActiveAdmin is "delete" but I have already tested deleting user with dependent records and it deleted the user with the records so I don't really know... Inserting your code returns in User model returns me the same error, I'm quite lost ...

Comment: ok, let's see if it's related to the user_id in notifications... try my revised code?

Comment: now revised... are there any other associations between User and Notificatoin?

Comment: Doesn't work either... I've updated my post so you can see the associations in my User and Notification models